# Square Text using aspectRatio in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to achieve a  following layout using Swift UI…

[image]

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        List(1...5) { index  in

            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Item number \(index)")
                    Spacer()
                    }.padding([.leading, .top, .bottom])
                    .background(Color.blue)

                Text("i")
                    .font(.title)
                    .italic()
                    .padding()
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                    .background(Color.pink)

                }.background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like the `Text("i")` to be square, but setting the `.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)` doesn't seem to do anything…

[image]

I could set the frame width and height of the text so it's square, but it seems that setting the aspect ratio should achieve what I want in a more dynamic way.

*What am I missing?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
List(1..<6) { index  in
                HStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Item number \(index)")
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding([.leading, .top, .bottom])
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    
                    Text("i")
                        .font(.title)
                        .italic()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                        .background(Color.pink)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                        .padding(.leading, 6)
                }
                .padding(6)
                .background(Color.yellow)
            }
```

The answer being said, i don't recommend giving SwiftUI too much freedom to decide the sizings. one of the biggest SwiftUI problems right now is the way it decides how to fit the views into each other. if something goes not-so-good on SwiftUI's side, it can result in too many calls to the UIKit's sizeToFit method which can slowdown the app, or even crash it.

but, if you tried this solution in a few different situations and it worked, you can assume that in your case, giving SwiftUI the choice of deciding the sizings is not problematic.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It was the `fixedSize` that I was missing

Comment: SwiftUI is such a weird MF. I just used ForEach instead of List and it crippled the whole view

Answer (score 4):

The issue is due to used different fonts for left/right sides, so paddings generate different resulting area.

Here is possible solution. The idea is to give right side rect based on default view size of left side text (this gives ability to track dynamic fonts sizes as well, automatically).

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var height = CGFloat.zero
    var body: some View {
        List(1...5, id: \.self) { index  in

            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Item number \(index)")
                    Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding([.leading, .top, .bottom])
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.blue.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                    })


                Text("i")
                    .italic()
                    .font(.title)
                    .frame(width: height, height: height)
                    .background(Color.pink)

                }
                .padding(8)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) {
                    self.height = $0
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it looks like there are a few ways to skin this particular cat.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to recreate the view in your first screenshot in SwiftUI. I wasn't sure on how much padding you wanted so I defined a `private` immutable variable for this value

The blue view is the one that will have the text content and could change in size so by using a `GeometryReader` you can get the size of the blue view and then use the height value from the size to set the width and height of the pink view. This means that whatever the height of the blue view is, the pink view will follow keeping an equal aspect ratio

The `SizeGetter` view below is used to get any views size using a `GeometryReader` and then binds that value back to a `@State` variable in the `ContentView`. Because the `@State` and `@Binding` property wrappers are being used, whenever the `blueViewSize` is updated SwiftUI will automatically refresh the view.

The `SizeGetter` view can be used for any view and is implemented using the `.background()` modifier as shown below

```swift
struct SizeGetter: View {

    @Binding var size: CGSize;

    var body: some View {

        // Get the size of the view using a GeometryReader
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Group { () -> AnyView in

                // Get the size from the geometry
                let size = geometry.frame(in: .global).size;

                // If the size has changed, update the size on the main thread
                // Checking if the size has changed stops an infinite layout loop
                if (size != self.size) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.size = size;
                    }
                }

                // Return an empty view
                return AnyView(EmptyView());
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    private let padding: Length = 10;
    @State private var blueViewSize: CGSize = .zero;

    var body: some View {

        List(1...5) { index  in

            // The yellow view
            HStack(spacing: self.padding) {

                // The blue view
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("Item number \(index)")
                            .padding(self.padding);
                    }
                    Spacer();
                }
                .background(SizeGetter(size: self.$blueViewSize))
                .background(Color.blue);

                // The pink view
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("i")
                        .font(.title)
                        .italic();
                }
                .frame(
                    width: self.blueViewSize.height,
                    height: self.blueViewSize.height
                )
                .background(Color.pink);
            }
            .padding(self.padding)
            .background(Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion it is better to set the background colour of a `VStack` or `HStack` instead of the `Text` view directly because you can then add more text and other views to the stack and not have to set the background colour for each one

Comment: Thanks, but as I noted at the end of the question, I'm trying to avoid setting a hardcoded value for the width / height of the pink square

Comment: @AshleyMills Sorry about that, please see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that… I've got to believe there is a simpler method though!

Comment: @AshleyMills No problem! Apple will probably add a less complex way to do this in a future version of SwiftUI but for now with SwiftUI still in beta, I don’t think there is another way

Comment: 10 month later did you find a nice way to make a textView square w/o GeometryReader?

Comment: @GrandSteph I didn’t no, I moved away from SwiftUI to let it mature. Not sure what Apple has added within the past few months, hopefully something to make this easier!

Answer (score 1):

I was searching very similar topic "Square Text in SwiftUI", came across your question and I think I've found quite simple approach to achieve your desired layout, using GeometryProxy to set width and heigh of the square view from offered geometry.size.

Checkout the code below, an example of TableCellView which can be used within List View context:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TableCellView: View {
    var index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Item number \(index)")
                    .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color(.systemBlue))
            .layoutPriority(1)
            
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                self.squareView(geometry: geometry)
            }
            .padding(.trailing)
        }
        .background(Color(.systemYellow))
        .padding(.trailing)
    }
    
    func squareView(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        Text("i")
            .frame(width: geometry.size.height, height: geometry.size.height)
            .background(Color(.systemPink))
    }
}
```

[image]